# Yii2: How to pass variable from views to controller without models?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model, yii2, send

I am using the ActiveForm widget to send a model from the view to the controller. It works great but now I also need to send a **checkbox that is not part of any model**. This is my checkbox:

```
<?= Html::checkbox('swim', false, ['id' => 'idSwim']) ?>
```

If my checkbox is part of a model, I could send it in this way:

```
<?= $form->field($myCheckboxModel, 'swim')->checkbox(['id' => 'idSwim') ?>
```

But it doesn't belong to any model, so I don't know how to send it. I even send different models in the same forms.

Comment: Your first line of code should work. It won't load the field into your model though, but you should be able to retrieve it from the POST array

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the posted value in your controller like this:

```
$swim = Yii::$app->request->post('swim')
```

If the field is related to one of your models, you could also consider defining it as a property: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-properties.html